# Can SQL 2008 and SQL 2008 R2 reside in a single machine?

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server-2008, installation

I do know that it would be much better if I try it first.
But the problem is that its my client's dedicated server with many websites running on it.
So, I cannot actually test that there.

The server is Windows Server 2008. My queries are

1. Does SQL 2008 R2 express and SQL 2008 reside on the same machine?
2. Does installing SQL 2008 R2 need OS upgrade to Windows Server 2008 R2?
3. What will the side effects of this be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, absolutely! SQL Server 2005 and later happily instance stacks together, and to be fair SQL Server 2000 does it quite well too.

Windows 2008 will be fine - I haven't personally tried that combination. Having said all that, I'd recommend always doing it on a scratch box first!

Two or more instances on the same OS will require their max memory setting to be configured appropriately, and both instances monitored for performance.

SQL Server 2008 requirements:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506(SQL.100).aspx

SQL Server 2008 R2 requirements:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506.aspx